# I'm looking for a wine recommendation to pair with to serve with carne asadas?

Tags: wine, recommendations, pairing

What wine would pair well with carne asadas? I enjoy chardonnay as my daily drinking wine. I was wondering if something would pair better.

Answer (score 3):

**What wine would pair well with *carne asadas*?**

Let us start by explaining what ***carne asadas*** is:

> [Carne asada](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carne_asada) is grilled and sliced beef, usually chuck steak (known as Diezmillo in Spanish), though skirt steak or flank steak can also be used. It is usually marinated then grilled or seared to impart a charred flavor. Carne asada can be served on its own or as an ingredient in other dishes.
>
> The term carne asada translates literally to "grilled meat"; the English-style dish "roast beef" is called by its English name in Spanish, so that each dish has a distinctive name. The term carne asada is used in Mexico and refers to the style of grilled meat in those countries. In South America, the term used for grilled meat is asado and it has a different style and preparation.
>
> **As an event**
>
> In Mexico and other countries in Central America, the phrase ***carne asada*** can also be used to describe a social event, the equivalent of a social barbecue, where family and close friends gather. ***Carne asada*** is especially popular in northern Mexico, where it is considered a staple food. It is the most common dish served at parties, celebrations, and other events in northern Mexico.

As a general rule, red wines pair well with red meats. There is no fixed absolute rule on this, but in general most people will pair a red wine with steak or beef.

As such I would recommend either a light red wine (Pinot Noir, Grenache or Barbera are some examples.) or a medium-bodied red wine (such as Merlot, Shiraz, Tempranillo or Nebbiolo).

Whatever you decide is fine. So ***bon appetite*** and enjoy your meal.

Comment: Good answer. I'd personally favor a Rioja.

Answer (score 2):

If the meat is quite "fatty" I can recommend a red wine with a higher base acidity in order to balance the fat of the meat.
For example a Sangiovese from Tuscany, Italy: Chianti (budget), Chianti Classico (medium) or Brunello di Montalcino (splurge)

Answer (score 1):

A great wine to pair with carne asada is a Malbec. Malbecs are full-bodied red wines with dark fruit flavors and a hint of spice, which pairs perfectly with the smoky, savory flavors of carne asada.